# Get Link Element cssRules/Rules in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, element

Obviously in JavaScript, we can look up all the CSS rules for the entire document by doing the follow:

```
- document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
```

Is there anyway to get a CSS Link element from the header of the document and the only the rules for that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<link>` element has a [`sheet` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-LinkStyle) which does exactly that:

```
document.getElementById('myStyle').sheet.cssRules
```

Of course, this is subject to [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: Turns out it was a timing issue (DOM not ready), so it does work.  Cheers!